# Use moviepy library to merge 2 Videos together Simple Question! Where is the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, moviepy

I use https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy library to merge two videos with python

```
import moviepy
clip1 = VideoFileClip("C:/folder/1.mp4",audio=True)
clip2 = VideoFileClip("C:/folder/2.mp4",audio=True)
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip1,clip2],method="compose")
final_clip.write_videofile("merged.mp4")
```

Where will I find the merged.mp4 file now?
Maybe this will help to https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html
Please help me.

Or is there another way to merge two videos with py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use it like that, in the current working directory where the script is called.
I.e. if you're in `C:\py` and call:
`>python merge.py`
it will be in `C:\py`

You can set a full path if you wish, `r"C:\Video\merged.mp4"` etc.

Also, if you want to only concatenate without effects or transitions, using `method='chain'` will be faster. See: [MoviePy write_videofile taking hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65526726/moviepy-write-videofile-taking-hours)

Comment: Thanks, can I ask you something else?

Comment: Oh I forget my question Thanks... xD